# Ubuntu 15.10 not detecting serial connections

Tags: serial-port

When trying to connect a serial modem to my ubuntu box (to be used by an application), I found that the system did not detect the presence of the modem (using dmesg and setserial commands). The output of setserial -g command shows uart as unknown for all ttyS* ports. Any hints about what could be wrong (any missing packages, modification to kernal and kernel modules) that could solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: It would be very helpful if we would know the make and model of the modem.

Comment: it is the Multiteck modem MT5600ZDXV (a 56K Voice/Data/Fax Modem)

Comment: The only reference to this modem that I found via Google is something from the Redhat 6.2 era - that must be before 2000. I don't know how, if at all, much support there is in modern Linux kernels.